# ModuleNotFoundError with torch

Tags: python, torch, modulenotfounderror, sentence-transformers

Im currently trying to implement a NLP text classification task that make use of the sentence_transformers package. When importing said package the following error is raised:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.ao.nn.intrinsic.modules.fused'

It seems to me that there are some dependency- or downloading problems with the torch extensions as the same error is raised when trying to import torch in an isolated script. Is there anyone that have encountered the same problem or at least something similar? Im at lost here.

I've tried downloading different versions of the torch package and its extensions, and find some info on requirements without success.

Thx in advance

---EDIT---

Im working with python version 3.8.10 in a virtual environment. The call stack when importing torch is:

```
    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import torch

File c:\path\MTW_Projects\Active_BERTOPIC\venvBERTOPIC\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py:1263
   1261 # nn.quant* depends on ao -- so should be after those.
   1262 import torch.nn.quantizable
-> 1263 import torch.nn.quantized
   1264 import torch.nn.qat
   1265 import torch.nn.intrinsic

File c:\path\MTW_Projects\Active_BERTOPIC\venvBERTOPIC\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\quantized\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from . import dynamic  # noqa: F403
      2 from . import functional  # noqa: F403
      3 from . import modules  # noqa: F403

File c:\path\MTW_Projects\Active_BERTOPIC\venvBERTOPIC\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\quantized\dynamic\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from torch.ao.nn.quantized.dynamic import *  # noqa: F403

File c:\path\MTW_Projects\Active_BERTOPIC\venvBERTOPIC\lib\site-packages\torch\ao\nn\quantized\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from . import functional
      2 from .modules import *  # noqa: F403
      3 from .modules import MaxPool2d
...
----> 1 from .fused import _FusedModule  # noqa: F401
      2 from .fused import ConvBn1d
      3 from .fused import ConvBn2d

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.ao.nn.intrinsic.modules.fused'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're working within an environment.
If you could show snapshots of your work environment and the error that'd help.

Comment: Does the edit clarify the error?

Comment: @CarlArthur
I've tried replicating the error and can't seem to get same.
I'd suggest you `pip uninstall torch` , reinstall the latest package and try again.